# Writing a char matrix to Excel using xlswrite

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, cell-array

Could someone assist in writing a char matrix to Excel? The following is a <17x6 char>

```
A =

SPK01a
SPK03a
SPK03b
SPK05a
SPK07a
SPK07b
SPK07c
SPK09a
SPK11a
SPK15a
SPK17a
SPK19a
SPK21a
SPK23a
SPK25a
SPK27a
SPK29a
```

I was trying to do `xlswrite(filename, {A})` but receive the error:

```
Error using xlswrite (line 220)
ActiveX - Element of a cell array cannot be a character matrix.
```

I need the strings to be in cells, so in this case, in the first column in Excel, in 17 separate cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cellstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) to make a properly shaped cell array:

```
xlswrite(fileName,cellstr(A))
```

`cellstr` provides a quick way to place each row of a character array into a separate cell, and it will *remove trailing spaces* at the end of each row.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to convert your matrix of characters into a cell array and use that to write into an excel file -

```
xlswrite(xls_filename,mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1))))
```

This will write everything to the first column of the excel sheet, but in different rows.